# Как изменить язык ОС Android из приложения имея Root?

Tags: android

На эмуляторе имеются Root права, проверял [так](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8097801) и [так](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6563615). Нужно из приложение изменить язык интерфейса операционной системы `Android` установленной на устройстве. Пока не получается. Пробовал например так:

```
private void setLang() {
    String command = "setprop persist.sys.language fr; setprop persist.sys.country CA; " +
                "setprop ctl.restart zygote";

    try {
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        Log.d("appLog", "adb start");
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            Log.d("appLog", line);
        }

        Log.d("appLog", "adb end");
        bufferedReader.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("appLog", "error", e);
    }
}
```

Код не работает.

Comment: Команду и аргументы нужно передавать в виде массива строк, а не одной строкой с пробелами.

Comment: @woesss попробовал и так. Результата нет.

Comment: Поменяйте `getInputStream()` на `getErrorStream()` и посмотрите что напишет. Если не ошибаюсь, рут права нужно запросить для процесса перед выполнением команд. По примеру из этого ответа попробуйте: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8750977

Comment: @woesss получаю "setprop: Max 2 arguments" нужно видимо другую команду использоватью

Answer (score 3):

У Вас три команды, их нельзя выполнить одновременно - сделайте как в примере через `OutputStream` по одной команде.

```
Process p =  Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
p.getOutputStream().write("setprop persist.sys.language fr".getBytes());
p.getOutputStream().write("setprop persist.sys.country CA".getBytes());
p.getOutputStream().write("setprop ctl.restart zygote".getBytes());
```

Comment: Спасибо. Получаю "Cannot run program "su": error=13, Permission denied" возможно не правильно получил root права. Ставил их на эмулятор.

Comment: Возможно, посмотрите статейку в тему: [Нет Root прав, хотя я их получал!](https://androidp1.ru/net-root-prav-hotya-ya-ih-poluchal-proveryaem-nalichie-root-android/).

Comment: @iamtihonov, `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_SUPERUSER"/>` в манифест добавили?

Comment: Не помогло и кажется разрешение устарело http://su.chainfire.eu/#updates-permission